# SQL many to many grouping onto one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I did use the search but the few results didn't seem to answer my specific question (or my sql skills are not good enough to apply the answers to my scenario)

I have tables I need to join.  The context is a delivery business.  One table contains the delivery round schedule.  All I need from this table is the date the customer signed up for weekly deliveries.  This is joined on the account number.

The other table contains, the account number, the delivery date instance etc

What I am looking to do is extract the average number of deliveries to each account number for the last 6 weeks.  But only for accounts that have a start date of between 6 and 10 weeks ago.

The code I am using seems to bring back the correct date ranges but, I need one row per account number with one average number of deliveries for the 6 week period.  The code I am using doesn't do this correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

THankyou

```
select mov.AccountNumber,
sch.contractStart,
mov.TypeOfMovement,
mov.Outlet,
mov.RoundName,
mov.VehicleType,
avg(mov.NumberofItems)


FROM [round_movements]mov  
left outer join [schedule]sch on sch.AccountNumber=
mov.AccountNumber                          
where mov.outlet='County'
and DATEDIFF(week, sch.ContractStart,GETDATE()) in(10,9,8,7,6)
and DATEDIFF(week, mov.RoundDate,GETDATE()) in (6,5,4,3,2,1,0)

group by 
mov.AccountNumber,
mov.RoundName,
sch.contractStart,
mov.TypeOfMovement,
mov.Outlet,
mov.VehicleType,
mov.NumberofItems
order by mov.AccountNumber
```

**Result with code above:**

```
 ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ AccountNumber   contractStart  Outlet   RoundName       VehicleType   Avg  No of Items ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 4000461         27/11/2013    town1     E4 (Wednesday)  sprinter       1               ║
           ║
║ 6382401         29/10/2013    town2     E1 (Thursday)   sprinter       2               ║
║ 6382401         29/10/2013    town2     E1 (Thursday)   sprinter       2               ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

**Expected Result:**

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ AccountNumber   contractStart   Outlet  RoundName      VehicleType Avg No Items     ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 4000461         27/11/2013      town 1  E4 (Wednesday)  sprinter    1               ║
║ 6382401         29/10/2013      town2   E1 (Thursday)   sprinter    2               ║
║            ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

**Result after making change suggested below by Rs:**

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ AccountNumber   contractStart   Outlet  RoundName      VehicleType Avg No Items     ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║   
  4000461   27/11/2013  Bristol E4 (Wednesday)  RCV 1
  6382401   29/10/2013  Bristol E1 (Thursday)   RCV 2
  6382401   29/10/2013  Bristol E1 (Thursday)   RCV 2

          ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Group by AccountNUmber, contractStart, outlet, roundname

Comment: I added the sql-server tag because the query syntax strongly suggests SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm using SQL server 2008 R2.  THanks.

Comment: remove mov.NumberofItems from group by columns list

Comment: Thanks rs.  I tried removing this but there are still multiple rows per account number:(

Answer (score 0):

Try this, remove `mov.NumberofItems` from group by columns list

```
select mov.AccountNumber,
sch.contractStart,
mov.TypeOfMovement,
mov.Outlet,
mov.RoundName,
mov.VehicleType,
avg(mov.NumberofItems)


FROM [round_movements]mov  
left outer join [schedule]sch on sch.AccountNumber=
mov.AccountNumber                          
where mov.outlet='County'
and DATEDIFF(week, sch.ContractStart,GETDATE()) in(10,9,8,7,6)
and DATEDIFF(week, mov.RoundDate,GETDATE()) in (6,5,4,3,2,1,0)

group by 
mov.AccountNumber,
mov.RoundName,
sch.contractStart,
mov.TypeOfMovement,
mov.Outlet,
mov.VehicleType
order by mov.AccountNumber
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick replies.  I removed number of items from group by but still get multiple rows per account number:(

Comment: I added to the original question - as you can see there ares till more than one row per account number - it seems to duplicate the avg no of items for each account number.  Thanks again for the help

Comment: what is expected result based on new result set? It is not clear which columns you are trying to group by or return averaged data for. Do you want to return minimum contract start date and average of items?

Comment: Really sorry, the results were incorrect on my original question (old piece of code I think).  I've updated to show what my code produces, your suggestion and what I need.  I just need to group by account number and show average of all items delivered across all round dates.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of things that will stop you from getting the results you were expecting.

1. You don't need the mov.NumberofItems in the group by because you are averaging it.
2. You need use the MIN function to give the first contract start date eg min(sch.contractStart) you then don't need sch.contractStart in the group by.

This should give you the results you are expecting.

So your query will something like this.

```
select 
  mov.AccountNumber,
  min(sch.contractStart),
  mov.TypeOfMovement,
  mov.Outlet,
  mov.RoundName,
  mov.VehicleType,
  avg(mov.NumberofItems)
FROM 
  [round_movements]mov  
  left outer join [schedule]sch on sch.AccountNumber=mov.AccountNumber                          
where 
  mov.outlet='County'
  and DATEDIFF(week, sch.ContractStart,GETDATE()) in(10,9,8,7,6)
  and DATEDIFF(week, mov.RoundDate,GETDATE()) in (6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
group by 
  mov.AccountNumber,
  mov.RoundName,
  mov.TypeOfMovement,
  mov.Outlet,
  mov.VehicleType,
  mov.NumberofItems
order by 
  mov.AccountNumber
```

Comment: Thankyou - my code is the same as above but still the results are as above - the same as Rs's suggestion - more than one line per account with duplicated avg no of items :( really annoying sorry

Comment: Rs's sugguestion doesn't include the min(sch.contractStart) for the contract start date.

Comment: The reason you are getting extra rows is because the dates aren't identical so you get a separate row for each

Comment: When I use the min() the results are the same becuase there is only one contract start date per account.  There are multiple round dates but only one contract start date

Answer (score 0):

Appending to what others have said:

The reason you are getting multiple results is `sch.contractStart` is different for 2 account numbers for 2 records.
What you can do is wrap `sch.contractStart` in `MAX()` and remove it from `GROUP BY`. This will give you the latest contract start date for particular account number which I believe makes sense from logical perspective.

**EDIT - After OP's question edit**
I can see with updated results, there are 2 exactly same records.
You could wrap entire thing into `SELECT DISTINCT` eliminate that. But that's not the proper way.

Actually, I don't see any reason for duplicate records if everything is in group by or aggregate function.
Have you removed `mov.NumberofItems` from `GROUP BY`?

Comment: And also remove `mov.NumberofItems` from `GROUP BY`. Its already wrapped in aggregating function

Comment: Thankyou.  I think the dataset had an error when I ran the original code. When I re-ran there is only one contract start date for each account number.  I've updated my original question with this..sorry to make this harder for you